# Склеивание строк в Android

Tags: java, строки, textview

У меня есть

```
private TextView ADDITIONAL_ACCESSORIES_RECOMMENDATION;
```

в который мне надо добавить несколько `String`. 
Я делаю так:

`ADDITIONAL_ACCESSORIES_RECOMMENDATION.setText(R.string.O_A_recommendation_umbrella + R.string.O_A_recommendation_gloves);`

Но в на телефоне выводятся цифры, а не текст. Как сделать так, чтобы выводилось несколько `String` в одном `TextView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`R.string.O_A_recommendation_gloves` это `id` (типа `int`) ресурса строки, и вы складываете эти 2 `id` и получаете непонятно какое число и в `setText` происходит попытка получить ресурс по этому непонятному `id`. Даже странно, что не вылетает, а показывает какие-то цифры, возможно, повезло наткнуться на существующий ресурс.

Чтобы получить строку по `id` в активити или фрагменте нужно использовать метод `getString(stringId)`

```
ADDITIONAL_ACCESSORIES_RECOMMENDATION.setText(
    getString(R.string.O_A_recommendation_umbrella) +
    getString(R.string.O_A_recommendation_gloves)
);
```